# How to write to our own calendar via the Google Calendar API (v3)

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I need to write to a Google Calendar from data in our datastore (App Engine app).

I want to access via OAuth 2.

Reading is no problem - the calendar is public and I just use the simple API access method.

Writing is a "problem" - obviously I need to authenticate. However, the calendar is owned by the app administrators, and we want to write to the calendar as a background task - no user interaction is required.

I have gone through all Google's documentation, but I feel none the wiser - how can I do a one -time setup for permanent write access to a Google Calendar, via the V3 API?

Comment: what kind of additional feature you want to add to Google Calendar ?

Comment: additional feature? I want to write to a calendar - write events onto a calendar programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make calls on behalf of your App Engine app without user interaction you should make use of the App Identity module:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/

If you are using the Google API Client Libraries, using the AppAssertionCredentials object will do this automatically for you:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts

Note the following:

1. You will probably still need to supply the simple key in order to attribute quota usage to the right project.
2. The App Identity module won't work during local App Engine development - you will need to deploy into production in order to obtain valid credentials.
3. You will need to share the calendar you are writing to with the email address associated with the service account for the App Engine app. To find this email address go to the App Engine Administration Console -> "Application settings" and look for the service account email.

Finally, I'm not 100% sure that the Calendar API allows service accounts direct access, but you should give this a try.  If that doesn't work for you an alternative may be to generate a refresh token for a real user that has access to the calendar, and look at embedding that into your application - the service account method is preferable, so I would try that first.

Comment: Hi! ok, this looks good, but your point 2 is an absolute killer - I can't test this in local development!

I've adapted my code to work with the AppAssertionCredentials object and yes, I now get a new "Invalid Credentials" error when I actually try to write. Setting up a staging to test now.

Comment: Ok, confirmed working on a staging server. This is great! I was absolutely breaking my head on the google oauth2 docs. I simply didn't see that there are extra helper classes for app engine, and especially like this for google to google services.